# ERROR: Error installing rails zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeitwerk

I recently changed my laptop and tried installing rails with

```
gem install rails
```

and I got this error

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.4.4.
```

I have installed ruby version 2.4.4, 2.5.7, and 2.6.5 and I'm still getting the same error.
Any pointers how to resolve this will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: How did you install Ruby, and how do you know what versions of Ruby you have, and how do you know that you're using Ruby >= 2.4.4 when you try to install Rails?

Comment: I installed ruby using  ```rbenv install  2.5.7 ``` and switched to 2.5.7 with ```rbenv global 2.5.7```

Comment: Did you `rbenv rehash`? https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-rehash What does `ruby -v` return?

Comment: yes I did ```rbenv rehash```  and ```ruby  -v``` returns ```ruby 2.5.7p206 (2019-10-01 revision 67816) [x86_64-darwin18]```.

Comment: I had the same error, try:
`rvm install 2.4.4` and then `rvm use 2.4.4`

Comment: @AyoguChibueze, did you solve this issue?

Comment: @codemick yes I uninstalled everything and started afresh. Just ensure all your gem are installed in one folder and the version manager you are using has access to it.

Answer (score 2):

In directory wanted use `rvm use ruby-2.5.7` command line to force the usage of this specific version of ruby and after `gem install rails`. Just tryed minutes ago and works fine

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround for this specific issue if you don't care about having a newer version of Ruby (and `rails`), you can just install the most recent compatible version of `rails` with your version of ruby, a similar example with `sprockets` which requires `ruby v2.5.0` solved by installing an older version of `rails v4.1.16` looking at the [dependencies graph](https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.1.16/dependencies):

```
sudo gem install rails -v 4.1.16
```